# Cancel access to property/method when getElementById returns null

Tags: javascript, dom, null, getelementbyid

For a variety of reasons, sometimes when I call `document.getElementById` on a DOM element, I get a null reference back. That's fine except that if I try to immediately access some property/method of a null reference, I'll get an error.

For example, with the following code, if there is no element in the DOM with an ID of `a`, then an attempt to access the `style` property of the returned `null` value will fail:

```
document.getElementById('a').style.background = 'red';
```

Is there any way to write a function, etc. that uses `document.getElementById` to get a DOM element, and in the event `null` is returned, cancel any immediate access attempts to DOM properties/methods for that null reference?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store it in a variable, that way you also have a cached reference to your element:

```
var aTag = document.getElementById('a');
if(aTag != null) {
  aTag.style.background = 'red';
}
```

But if you *really* wanted a function, you could pass in an anonymous function to a method which is only called if the first parameter is not null:

```
safeAccess(document.getElementById("aTag"), function(a) {
  a.style.background = 'red';
});

function safeAccess(elem, scriptToExecute) {
  if(elem != null) {
    scriptToExecute(elem);
  }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Thank you. I was hoping that there was some built-in function, etc. that would allow you to cancel all subsequent actions on a null reference, but your function works just as well as it doesn't require any addition calls to the DOM and it doesn't require you to store the DOM element in a variable first. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in a try/catch block. No matter what happends inside that block, the execution will continue. But "can" doesn't mean "should". Code written like that is potentially harder to debug.

```
try {
    document.getElementById('a').style.background = 'red';
} catch (o) {}
```

Comment: Agree with the *doesn't mean should*, you would be ignoring a lot of things which could potentially go wrong in that line of code.

Answer (score -1):

Just check if it's null first.

```
if (document.getElementById('a'))
    document.getElementById('a').style.background = 'red';
```

Comment: Maybe if you loop through it 1000 times at once, otherwise it will perform the same.

Comment: I agree. If I was going to reference the same DOM element twice in a row, I would definitely store it in a variable first. Granted, on a small scale, in wouldn't matter, but all the same, it's not a good coding practice in JS, I think.